# What is the justification behind the principle of corresponding states?

Tags: thermodynamics

Two fluids with same reduced volume and temperature have the same reduced pressure.

Two fluids with same reduced pressure and temperature have the same compression factor.

What justifies these two statements and why exactly are both saying the same thing?